# remove div in jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a repeater, within that there is a button. and onclientclick of that button the respective div should be removed  followed by a db query using ajax.

when i am doing just div.remove() its working fine. but when i place the remove code in the success part of the ajax.. its not working..but after page refreshing its working fine..

my code is...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="grid_4" data-gen="afc" data-gen-offset="bottom-in-view" id='<%#Eval("Id") %>'>
                                <a class="services-block" href="#">
                                    <ul class="icon">
                                        <li class="fontawesome-icon large circle-two fa fa-laptop"></li>
                                        <li class="fontawesome-icon large circle-deg-two fa fa-laptop"></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblGameTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GameName") %>'></asp:Label></p>
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblOpponent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OpponentOne") + "  Vs.  "+ Eval("OpponentTwo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%# "Date : "+ Eval("GameDate") + "<br />Time : " + Eval("GameTime") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        <br />

                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnBlue" runat="server" Text="High" GroupName="UrlColor" Checked="true" />
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnRed" runat="server" Text="Low" GroupName="UrlColor" />


                                        <asp:Button ID="btnOpponentOne" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OpponentOne") %>' OnClientClick="opponentOne(this);"/>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnOpponentTwo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OpponentTwo") %>' OnClientClick="opponentTwo(this);"/>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnDraw" runat="server" Text="Draw" OnClientClick="Draw(this);"/>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="gid" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="opOne" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("OpponentOne") %>' />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="opTwo" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("OpponentTwo") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                   <%-- <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />--%>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the js is...

```
function opponentOne(btn) {
            var s = btn.id;
            var start = s.indexOf("btnOpponentOne");
            var end = s.lastIndexOf("_");
            sub = s.substring(start, end);
            s = s.replace(sub, "opOne");
            var hidden = document.getElementById(s);
            var id = hidden.value;  /* option */
            //alert(id);
            var divId = aaaa1(btn);
            //alert(divId);
            var check = CheckRadio(btn);
            //alert(check);
            var tid = getParameterByName('tid');
            //alert(tid);
            var inputText = id + "~" + divId + "~" + check+"~"+tid;    /* option + div id(id) + high/low */
            /* database connection */
            if (confirm('Are your sure ?')) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/play_match.aspx/AddPrediction",
                    data: '{\'InputText\':\'' + inputText + '\'}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.d == "Success") {
                            alert('done..............'+divId);
                            $('#' + divId).remove();
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert('fail');
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('error');
                        alert(response.d);`enter code here`
                    }
                });
            }

        }
```

Comment: Does the alert works immediately or also just after refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of updatepanel. see this link to get a clear picture http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534587/ASP-NET-jQuery-is-not-Working-in-UpdatePanels

Answer (score 0):

you will have to explicitly refresh the update panel to refresh the UI. try using  __doPostBack(UpdatePanel1, ''); to update it. good luck.